# Fine tuning image stitching in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, 2d, image-stitching

(A newbie in computer vision)

Goal is to reconstitute a game level using image stitching or **any other** method. The level played by someone is video-recorded, these frames will be the input.

Expected result : (level 4-4 of SMB from http://www.vgmaps.com/)
[image]

This is my first attempt at addressing this problem, using OpenCV (EmguCV). So far results are excellent but I was wondering whether there are more appropriate techniques knowing that my input will be strictly in 2D ?

I am open to try another framework/technique providing it's not overly complex.

Here are source images :

[image]

Result of the 7 first images :
(for some reasons, the Stitcher in OpenCV did not accept 10 at once ...)

[image]

Result of the last 3 images :

[image]

Comment: The question is much clear now.

Comment: For the Mario Bros example at least it would be difficult to do image stitching, as there is an aliasing problem (the pattern is repetitive). I suppose some sort of relatively high frequency feature tracking is necessary to register consecutive images in the video (said in other words, you cannot use images distant to each other otherwise you would have a lot of ambiguities)